# Visual Basic dividing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, loops, basic

I'm on visual basic and I'm reading through some piece of code my teacher wrote, he had this chunck of code:

```
 Private Sub btnDividing_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDividing.Click
    Dim number As Integer = InputBox("Divide number by 2:")
    Dim result As Integer = 0

    Do While (number <> 0)
        result += 1 
        number = number - 2
    Loop
    MsgBox("The result is: " & result, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

End Sub
```

So my teacher typed the *result += 1* and *number = number -2*  I didn't really understand that part so i tried simplifying it by changing it to:

```
    Dim number As Integer = InputBox("Divide number by 2:")
    Dim result As Integer = 0

    Do While (number <> 0)
        result = number / 2
    Loop
    MsgBox("The result is: " & result, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

End Sub
```

but it keeps freezing after I click "OK"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note:  This is not VBA, so I edited the tags to say it was VB.Net.  (I'm pretty certain that will be correct.)

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend Option Strict https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/4022/option-strict and `Dim number = Val(InputBox("Divide number by 2:"))` as InputBox returns a String

Comment: There is a huge assumption that number will be even.  If it is not it will be a loop.  Maybe the teacher meant > 0 instead of <> 0.  Let's hope so.

Comment: The bit of code you dont understand counts the number of times that 2 can be taken away from `number`(it's also badly written). Say you enter 6 as the number. The `Do..While..Loop` should be `Do While (number > 0)`. Say you enter 6 as the number, the loop will check if `number` is >0. If it is, 1 is added to the counter(`result`) and 2 is taken away from `number`. So now `number` =4. The loop checks again that number >0 and if it is adds 1 to `result` and takes 2 from `number`. Now `result`=2 and `number`=2. Loop again and `result`=3 and `number=0. Because `number is 0 now, the loop will exit.

Comment: So your final `result` will =3 which is the same as 6/2. If you try your teacher's un altered code with 5, you will end up looping for ever, because `number` will always be <>0. and never equal 0. Try it with pen and paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It freezes because you made it an infinite loop:

```
Do While (number <> 0)
    result = number / 2
Loop
```

The loop checks the value of `number`, but your modified code in the loop never *modifies* the value of `number`.  So if the condition is true the first time it's checked, it will always be true.  The original code modified the value:

```
Do While (number <> 0)
    result += 1 
    number = number - 2
Loop
```

Since `number` is decremented by `2` with each iteration of the loop, it will eventually (assuming it's even) be equal to `0`, making the loop condition false and the loop will end.

Basically, a loop needs to in some way modify the values being checked in the condition (or have some other control statement to exit the loop) or the loop will infinitely run.